# C++ - Function is completely skipped if an internal variable exceeds ~60,000

Tags: c++11

I wrote the following for a class, but came across some strange behavior while testing it. `arrayProcedure` is meant to do things with an array based on the 2 "tweaks" at the top of the function (`arrSize`, and `start`). For the assignment, `arrSize` must be 10,000, and `start`, 100. Just for kicks, I decided to see what happens if I increase them, and for some reason, if `arrSize` exceeds around 60,000 (I haven't found the exact limit), the program immediately crashes with a stack overflow when using a debugger:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x008F6977 in TMA3Question1.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x00A32000).
```

If I just run it without a debugger, I don't get any helpful errors; windows hangs for a fraction of a second, then gives me an error `TMA3Question1.exe has stopped working`.

I decided to play around with debugging it, but that didn't shed any light. I placed breaks above and below the call to `arrayProcedure`, as well as peppered inside of it. When `arrSize` doesn't exceed 60,000 it runs fine: It pauses before calling `arrayProcedure`, properly waits at all the points inside of it, then pauses on the break underneath the call.

If I raise `arrSize` however, the break before the call happens, but it appears as though it never even steps into `arrayProcedure`; it immediately gives me a stack overflow without pausing at any of the internal breakpoints.

The only thing I can think of is the resulting arrays exceeds my computer's current memory, but that doesn't seem likely for a couple reasons:

1. It should only use just under a megabyte:

   - sizeof(double) = 8 bytes
   - 8 * 60000 = 480000 bytes per array
   - 480000 * 2 = 960000 bytes for both arrays
2. As far as I know, arrays aren't immediately constructed when I function is entered; they're allocated on definition. I placed several breakpoints before the arrays are even declared, and they are never reached.

Any light that you could shed on this would be appreciated.

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

//CLOCKS_PER_SEC is a macro supplied by ctime
double msBetween(clock_t startTime, clock_t endTime) {
    return endTime - startTime / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000.0);
}

void initArr(double arr[], int start, int length, int step) {
    for (int i = 0, j = start; i < length; i++, j += step) {
        arr[i] = j;
    }
}

//The function we're going to inline in the next question
void helper(double a1, double a2) {
    std::cout << a1 << " * " << a2 << " = " << a1 * a2 << std::endl;
}


void arrayProcedure() {
    const int arrSize = 70000;
    const int start = 1000000;

    std::cout << "Checking..." << std::endl;
    if (arrSize > INT_MAX) {
        std::cout << "Given arrSize is too high and exceeds the INT_MAX of: " << INT_MAX << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    double arr1[arrSize];
    double arr2[arrSize];

    initArr(arr1, start, arrSize, 1);
    initArr(arr2, arrSize + start - 1, arrSize, -1);

    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
        helper(arr1[i], arr2[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    using namespace std;

    const clock_t startTime = clock();

    arrayProcedure();

    clock_t endTime = clock();
    cout << endTime << endl;
    double elapsedTime = msBetween(startTime, endTime);

    cout << "\n\n" << elapsedTime << " milliseconds. ("
        << elapsedTime / 60000 << " minutes)\n";
}
```

Comment: The test `if (some_int_var > INT_MAX)` should make you IMMEDIATELY sceptical. How do you imagine could this condition *ever* be `true`? Think carefully about what `INT_MAX` means.

Comment: It really is just a stack overflow. If you run it with a higher default stack size the program runs just fine.

Comment: I just threw that in as an attempt mitigate too high of values from being entered, but it retrospect, ya, it won't work. If I take it out though, the same behaviour happens.

Comment: @DAhrens How is that the case? I'm not even using much memory.

Comment: Also you forgot to include limits.h to have the INT_MAX value.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Berry Blue answered that question below.

Comment: @DAhrens VS allows it. It must be an auto-import or something. I'll add the import manually for compatibility. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default stack size is 1 MB with Visual Studio.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks.aspx

You can increase the stack size or use the new operator.

```
double *arr1 = new double[arrSize];
double *arr2 = new double[arrSize];
...
delete [] arr1;
delete [] arr2;
```

Comment: Wow. 1mb seems really small. Thank you. Why does it crash immediately though? Are my assumptions in Point 2 incorrect?

Comment: “use `new` operator” – No, really no. Use `std::vector` instead. @Carcigenicate 1 MB stack size is actually plenty for normal applications.

Comment: @Konrad I have to use arrays for the assignment. Why not use `new`? Because it's bad practice to have bare `new`s not controlled by RAII?

Comment: @Konrad And I'm still curious as to why it immediately crashes, instead of crashing once it hits `double arr1[arrsize]`. Did the compiler have it allocate at the beginning for some reason?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes, bare `new`s are bad exactly for this reason. If it’s for an assignment, ignore what I said. As for why it crashes immediately, stack allocations are typically handled as soon as the function is entered, not when the declaration statement is reached (declarations are actually never *executed* at runtime, they are statements for the compiler only, to reserve the necessary space and symbols; the only thing that would be executed would be an initialisation).

Comment: Thank you @Konrad. Berry solved my original problem, but you wrapped it up so it makes sense. Given my limitations for this assignment, would say say my best option is to just document the limit, and not worry about the exceeding cases?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes, I think this is an entirely appropriate course of action here.